# appending nodes into xslt array during foreach

Tags: xslt-3.0

I have xml (described below), i want to divide the contetn by the "`<eop/>`" element
where whenever there is an  tag itis a new element.
and save the the content in an global array (for later use)
i have a foreach loop over the xml grouped by eop
but i dont know how to append each group to the global array

this is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mainBody>
    <article_1>
        <content>
            <p>befre eop
                <eop eId="eop_386" /> 
                after oep
            </p>
        </content>
    </article_1>
    <article_2>
        <content>
            <p>point content</p>
        </content>
    </article_2>
    <article_3>
        <content>
            <p>point content</p>
        </content>
    </article_3>
    <article_4>
        <content>
            <p>before eop 387<eop eId="eop_387" /> after 387</p>
        </content>
    </article_4>
    <article_5>
        <content>
            <p> content 5</p>
        </content>
    </article_5>
    <article_6>
        <content>
            <p> before eop 388<eop eId="eop_388" /> after 388</p>
        </content>
    </article_6>
    <article_7>
        <content>
            <p>before eop 389<eop eId="eop_389" />
            </p>
        </content>
    </article_7>
</mainBody>
```

and this part of the xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="mainBody">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="descendant::node()" group-ending-with="eop" > 

    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

thanks

Comment: What would be the members of the array, what type of array are you looking for (array of sequences of nodes?)?

Comment: As you can't change the value of `global` variables what you might want to do is e.g. `<xsl:variable name="groups" as="array(node()*)*"><xsl:for-each-group ...><xsl:sequence select="array { current-group() }"/></xsl:for-each-group></xsl:variable>` and then `<xsl:variable name="groups" select="fold-left($groups, [], function($a, $a1) { array:append($a, $a1) }"/>` to get a single array of sequences of nodes.

Comment: yes the expected result is an array of sequences  node , in case of my example xml

Comment: the first item in the array should be "<article_1><content><p>befre eop"<eop eId="eop_386" />

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking for, are you just having difficulties writing out the code to split up the input based on the grouping you have used or do you really need an XSLT 3/XPath 3.1 array? If you want a globally scoped variable, you can always use e.g. `<xsl:variable name="groups" as="array(node()*)*"><xsl:for-each-group select="/mainBody/descendant::node()" group-ending-with="eop"><xsl:sequence select="array { current-group() }"/></xsl:for-each-group></xsl:variable>`. But with most questions here asking for an "array" I am not even sure if an XDM 3.1 array is meant.

Comment: I think it is exactly what I need, I am not familiar with xslt, so I understand my question wasn't clear enough, i need to use this data (the array content) in another template (Where I don't have access to this Xpath). my difficults is to save all the "current-group" in the foreach in an XSLT/XPath array. I tried the code written above. Inside the loop it looks good but in the end this is the array content (but mach longer...), [[net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.WhitespaceTextImpl@20c0a0, net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.WhitespaceTextImpl@20c10e]]']

Comment: Perhaps show us your other code as well and the result you want to achieve. If you have never processed XSLT 3.0/XPath 3.1 arrays then perhaps do some reading https://www.altova.com/training/xpath3/xpath-31#arrays, https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-arrays. I can't tell why your processing of the array sequence fails if you don't show the exact code and I can't tell what further processing you want if you don't show the transformation result you need, and perhaps also explain why you need separate templates.

Comment: The code you gave me worked for me! the problem is that the array "groups" is unknown where i need him, how can i declare this variable globally????

Comment: You can put `<xsl:variable name="groups" as="array(node()*)*"><xsl:for-each-group select="/mainBody/descendant::node()" group-ending-with="eop"><xsl:sequence select="array { current-group() }"/></xsl:for-each-group></xsl:variable>` globally (i.e. as a child of `xsl:stylesheet`) and that way it should be available in any template.

Comment: Good that we got you sorted, for a clear resolution of your question I have the suggestion from the latest comment into an answer; consider to accept it to mark your question as solved or write your own answer showing what you have finally used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put

```
<xsl:variable name="groups" as="array(node()*)*">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="/mainBody/descendant::node()" group-ending-with="eop">
    <xsl:sequence select="array { current-group() }"/>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:variable>
```

globally (i.e. as a child of xsl:stylesheet) and that way the variable `groups` of type sequence of array of nodes should be available in any template.